# When mapping an array of strings, getting undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How do I map an array of strings to be an array of JSON objects?  I have tried the below in the console

```
>> entityTypes = ["library"]
Array [ "library" ]

>> entityTypes.map(type => {name: type});
Array [ undefined ]
```

The resulting array is undefined.  I can hard-code things and they look fine

```
>> arr = [{name: "library"}]
Array [ {…} ]
```

So not sure what's going wrong with my map function.

Comment: you need to assign the return value of the map to a variable.

Comment: Do this `entityTypes.map(type => ({name: type}))` add `()` around `{name: type}`

Comment: @TheFool This is in a REPL context, so that isn’t necessary to see the results of the expressions.

Comment: Real JSON object the name in double quotes.

Comment: @evgenifotia, good catch. Thats the issue. Its a function body that diesnt return anything so undefined by default.